# White Column Header – Linked to item with edit menu (Change Background Color)

Tags: header

The column header for the “Linked to item with edit menu” is white. How do I change the background color of this column only to match the color of the rest of the header row without changing the color of the rows in the body; using the content editor? 
The inspect element is:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below CSS.

```
.ms-viewheadertr th[aria-label="Open Menu"] {
    background-color: #a28e5c;
}
```

[image]